# Get Total Rows From Join Based On Value From Join Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Im not sure about the title, anyone can edit as pleased

Table `articles`

```
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|   id     |  title                  | status   |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|    1     |  title 1                | accepted |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|    2     |  title 2                | accepted |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|    3     |  title 3                | rejected |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|    4     |  title 4                | accepted |
+----------+---------+---------------+----------+
```

Table `article_reviewers`

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
|   id     | article_id |  user_id  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     |     1      |     1     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    2     |     2      |     1     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    3     |     3      |     1     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    4     |     2      |     2     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

How can i find total of article for each user and for each status
from this table.

From table:
user with `id 1`, have 2 accepted article and 1 rejected article.
user with `id 2`, have 1 accepted article and 0 rejected article.

If i make something like:

```
SELECT count(*) total FROM article_reviewers ar
INNER JOIN articles a
ON ar.article_id = a.id
GROUP BY ar.user_id
```

I got total article for each user, how can i find for each status?
Can someone show me light on how to do this, im quite clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there:

```
SELECT ar.user_id, a.status, count(*) total
FROM article_reviewers ar
INNER JOIN articles a
ON ar.article_id = a.id
GROUP BY ar.user_id, a.status
```

Comment: gah, y i didnt even think to group by multiple column, i thought i need to resort to insane subquery..thx so much